# I was trying to implement the linkedlist from scratch in java , I am getting the following errors

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linked-list, static

I had written the code on sublime text & On the command prompt, I got the following error and I having difficulty in resolving, I have implemented the LinkedList class inside class data
error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
^
data.java:24: error: incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to data.LinkedList.Node
llist.head = new Node(1);
^
data.java:27: error: incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to data.LinkedList.Node
llist.head.next=second;

```
public class data{ 
 class LinkedList {
       Node head;
   class Node{
            int data;
            Node next; 
            public void Node(int data ){
            this.data = data;
            next=null;
            }
          }
public LinkedList(){}
public void printList(){
    Node n = head;
    while(n != null){
        System.out.println(n.data+" ");
        n=n.next;}
}
}
public static void main(String[]args){
System.out.println("in main ");
LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
llist.head = new Node(1); 
Node second=new Node(2);  
Node third=new Node(3);
llist.head.next=second;
second.next=third;
llist.printList();
}
}
```

Comment: Please help in resolving the error I have made a class data and inside that implemented the Linked List Class

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare inner classes static, if you want to instantiate them from static methods: `static class LinkedList`, `static class Node`.
2. Constructors have no `void` return type: `public Node(int data) {...}`.
3. Qualify the name of inner classes of inner classes: `new LinkedList.Node(...)`.

```
public class data {
    static class LinkedList {
        Node head;

        static class Node {
            int data;

            Node next;

            public Node(int data) {
                this.data = data;
                next = null;
            }
        }

        public LinkedList() {
        }

        public void printList() {
            Node n = head;
            while (n != null) {
                System.out.println(n.data + " ");
                n = n.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main ");
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();
        llist.head = new LinkedList.Node(1);
        LinkedList.Node second = new LinkedList.Node(2);
        LinkedList.Node third = new LinkedList.Node(3);
        llist.head.next = second;
        second.next = third;
        llist.printList();
    }
}
```

4. Indent your code properly.
5. Use an IDE like Eclipse for Java development - it helps you a lot finding problems like those.